# Number of permutations of $4$-digit password lock given that it must contains the digits $1$, $2$, and $3$

Tags: permutations

- Password has $4$ digits
- Each placeholder can take value from $0$ to $9$
- Must contain digits ($1$ AND $2$ AND $3$)
- Valid sequences are ($1123, 0231, 1023, \ldots$)
- Invalid sequences are ($0010, 9999, 0023, \ldots$)

How many valid permutations are there? What concept is this? Initially I thought it was a simple problem, but I can't figure out.

Comment: **(a)** Is 1,2,3 an *example* or are these to necessarily be the  distinct digits **(b)** Can the remaining digit be from one of the $3$ or does it have to exclude them ?

Answer (score 3):

The password will have $1$, $2$, $3$, and a fourth digit. We can do casework on the value of the fourth digit:

---

**Case 1**: The fourth digit is not $1$, $2$, or $3$.

In this case, there are $7$ choices for the value of the fourth digit. For each of these $7$ choices, there are $4!$ ways to arrange the digits into a password:

$$7 \cdot 4! \,= \,168$$

**Case 2**: The fourth digit is $1$.

In this case, there would be  $4!$ ways to arrange the digits if the $1$s were distinguishable, but since the $1$s are not distinguishable, we are overcounting by a factor of $2$ and we need to divide:

$$\frac{4!}{2} = 12$$

**Case 3**: The fourth digit is $2$.

In this case, the reasoning is the same as for Case 2:

$$\frac{4!}{2} = 12$$

**Case 4**: The fourth digit is $3$.

In this case, the reasoning is the same as for Cases 1 and 2:

$$\frac{4!}{2} = 12$$

---

This gives a final answer of

$$168 + 12 \cdot 3 \, = \, \boxed{204\,}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be the set of all passwords that contain 1, $B$, those contain 2 and $C$, those contain 3. We need the number of elements in $A\cap B \cap C$. Now, by inclusion exclusion formula,
\begin{align*}
|A^c \cup B^c \cup C^c| &= \binom{3}{1}9^4 - \binom{3}{2}8^4 + \binom{3}{3} 7^4
\end{align*}
Hence
\begin{align*}
|A\cap B \cap C| = 10^4 - |A^c \cup B^c \cup C^c| = 204
\end{align*}